# Button exists but its not clickable

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

when i search for the button it exists but when i try to click on it, it cannot find it and times out. How do I fix it?
i have the updated chrome driver. i have all the gems at the latest levels.

```
irb(main):189:0> ie.button(value:"OK").html
=> "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"javascript:makeList('1591993');\" value=\"OK\">"
irb(main):190:0> ie.button(value:"OK").exists?
=> true
irb(main):191:0> ie.button(value:"OK").click


2021-02-05 18:07:41 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError (ensure the driver supports W3C WebDriver specification) instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
        7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
        6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        5: from (irb):191
        4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:145:in `click'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:790:in `element_call'
        2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:803:in `rescue in element_call'
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:752:in `raise_present'
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException (element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Button: located: true; {:value=>"OK", :tag_name=>"button"}> to be present)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a high chance that there are two buttons with the values 'OK' and when you write `ie.button(value:"OK").click` it issue the click on the first button but it may be invisible. So if there are two buttons, the button you are seeing may be a second button. So first you execute the below code

```
p ie.buttons(value:"OK").count
```

And see if it prints 2 or 3(greater than one), if it prints, then you are actually interacting with the first button that's invisible. So you have to find out which button you would like to click, If count is exactly 2, then you could write the following code.

```
ie.buttons(value:"OK").last.click #I used buttons here not button
```

This will issue the click on the last button. If button count is more than two, then you could pass the index of the button to click the target button like below

```
ie.buttons(value:"OK")[3].last.click
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is exist but not clickable:

1. It's not visible: check its first by open the page manually, adjust its CSS
2. It's blocked by something. That may be a transparent block with higher z-index on it, or the button is blocked partially. Try to move the button to another wide-open space and run the script again.

Comment: None of this should be the reason. Button could be invisible when it exists.

Answer (score 0):

the fire_event method did the trick
ie.button(value:"OK").fire_event "onclick"

Comment: Fire_Event is using the javascript, that's not selenium click. You may be clicking the wrong element which is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the job done in most situation, will click present one

`@b.buttons(text: "OK").select(&:present?).first.click`

Sometimes watir click fails (for good reasons) so you do it with javascript,

`@b.buttons(text: "OK").select(&:present?).first.fire_event :click`

But you can also try sending enter keystroke

`@b.buttons(text: "OK").select(&:present?).first.send_keys :enter`

you can verify its working if you see expected button receiving the click